# Property 'token' does not exist on type '() => User'. any

Tags: angular

I get an error,

[ts] Property 'token' does not exist on type '() => User'.
any

I am using a user.ts file to a
    `export class User {
    id: number;
    username: string;
    password: string;
    firstName: string;
    lastName: string;
    token: string;
    }`

This is my authentication service ts file:

```
export class AuthenticationService {
private currentUserSubject: BehaviorSubject<User>;
public $currentUser: Observable<User>;

constructor(private http: HttpClient, ) {
    this.currentUserSubject = new BehaviorSubject<User>(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser')));
    this.$currentUser = this.currentUserSubject.asObservable();
   }
public currentUserValue(): User {
    return this.currentUserSubject.value;
}
```

I get an error when I instantiate a function from authentication service ts to jwtinterceptor ts file:

**[ts] Property 'token' does not exist on type '() => User'.
any**

```
    intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    // add authorization header with jwt token if available
    let currentUser = this.authenticationService.currentUserValue;
    if (currentUser && currentUser.token) {
        request = request.clone({
            setHeaders: { 
                Authorization: `Bearer ${currentUser.token}`
            }
        });
    }

    return next.handle(request);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this code `let currentUser = this.authenticationService.currentUserValue;` you are assigning the "function", not the result.

So just evaluate the function to get the returned object, replace with:

```
let currentUser = this.authenticationService.currentUserValue();
```

Answer (score 1):

You've defined `currentUserValue` as a function, not a property, so you have to call it to get `User` data.
you are not calling `this.authenticationService.currentUserValue`

Need an execution:

```
let currentUser = this.authenticationService.currentUserValue();
```